# Terraform map to string value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How do you parse a map variable to a string in a resource value with Terraform12?

I have this variable:

```
variable "tags" {
  type                = map
  default = {
    deployment_tool   = "Terraform"
    code              = "123"
  }
}
```

And want this: {deployment_tool=Terraform, code=123}

I've tried the following without success:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "myparamstore" {
  ***
  value = {
    for tag in var.tags:
      join(",",value, join("=",tag.key,tag.values))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your requested output is just malformed JSON string. So you can convert your variable to json using  `jsonencode`, and then remove `"` and change `:` into `=`:

```
value = replace(replace(jsonencode(var.tags), "\"", ""), ":", "=")
```

Comment: Revisiting upvote to note it seems weird there is no function for `Map` --> `List` when `List` --> `Map` exists as intermediary for `join`. Might be an interesting PR for Hacktoberfest.

Answer (score 25):

Replacing ":" with "=" is not a perfect solution, just consider a map with such a value: `https://example.com` - it becomes `https=//example.com`. That's not good.
So here is my solution:

```
environment_variables = join(",", [for key, value in var.environment_variables : "${key}=${value}"])
```